# Pagination in jQuery DataTable not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, pagination

Have been surfing and applying various solutions but the problems just isnt being solved. The dataTable doesnt paginate the table rows

```
$('#rates_table').DataTable({
    stateSave: true,
    "dom":'<"top"f>rt<"bottom"p><"clear">', 
    "lengthChange": true, 
    "pageLength":10, 
    "order": [[1, "desc"]]
});
```

Im using

jQuery.DataTables 1.10.7 and 
jQuery v2.1.4

Created a fiddle for it:-

https://jsfiddle.net/zdsL44xp/

Comment: A little more information on the problem you're running into would help. What's the issue you're running into specifically?

Comment: create a fiddle example or provide your `html+java-script` here so that we can help you

Comment: Works here -> **http://jsfiddle.net/0f9Ljfjr/920/**

Comment: in your example link `$(...).DataTable is not a function coming`. did you added datatable library there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to add jquery library first and then datatable library and it's css

You given code worked for me:-

```js
$('#customers_table').DataTable({
       stateSave: true,
      "dom":'<"top"f>rt<"bottom"p><"clear">', 
      "lengthChange": true, 
      "pageLength":10, 
      "order": [[1, "desc"]]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.0/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<table id="customers_table" width="100%" class="display table table-striped dataTable no-footer" border="0" cellpadding="5" role="grid" style="width: 100%;">
<thead>
  <tr class="header" role="row">
    <th align="left" class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="" style="width: 36px;"><input type="checkbox" class="checkall" name="item"></th>
    <th align="left" class="sorting_asc" tabindex="0" aria-controls="customers_table" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-sort="ascending" aria-label="Full Name: activate to sort column descending" style="width: 219px;">Full Name</th>
    <th align="center" class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="customers_table" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Email Address: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 212px;">Email Address</th>
    <th align="left" class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="customers_table" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Phone: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 111px;">Phone</th>
    <th align="left" class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="customers_table" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Policies: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 83px;">Policies</th>
    <th align="left" class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="customers_table" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Quotes: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 80px;">Quotes</th>
    <th align="left" class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="customers_table" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Date of Registration: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 192px;">Date of Registration</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr id="3" class="odd" align="left" role="row">
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="chkitem" value="[{&quot;function&quot;:&quot;delete&quot;,&quot;params&quot;:&quot;3,Betrand  Bella Start,winchestaer@gmail.com&quot;}]" name="item[]"></td>
    <td class="sorting_1"><a href="http://localhost/esurance365ec/admin/customers/show/3">Betrand  Bella Start</a></td>
    <td>winchestaer@gmail.com</td>
    <td>00238482734</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>25 Mar 17</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="5" class="even" align="left" role="row">
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="chkitem" value="[{&quot;function&quot;:&quot;delete&quot;,&quot;params&quot;:&quot;5,Muchiri Stanley N. Muchiri,sngumo@gmail.com&quot;}]" name="item[]"></td>
    <td class="sorting_1"><a href="http://localhost/esurance365ec/admin/customers/show/5">Muchiri Stanley N. Muchiri</a></td>
    <td>sngumo@gmail.com</td>
    <td>722958720</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>04 Apr 17</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="2" class="odd" align="left" role="row">
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="chkitem" value="[{&quot;function&quot;:&quot;delete&quot;,&quot;params&quot;:&quot;2,Okore Jumbe More,okore@gmail.com&quot;}]" name="item[]"></td>
    <td class="sorting_1"><a href="http://localhost/esurance365ec/admin/customers/show/2">Okore Jumbe More</a></td>
    <td>okore@gmail.com</td>
    <td>072438934</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>24 Mar 17</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="4" class="even" align="left" role="row">
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="chkitem" value="[{&quot;function&quot;:&quot;delete&quot;,&quot;params&quot;:&quot;4,Rude Bwoyi,TRENDA45@YAHOO.COM&quot;}]" name="item[]"></td>
    <td class="sorting_1"><a href="http://localhost/esurance365ec/admin/customers/show/4">Rude Bwoyi</a></td>
    <td>TRENDA45@YAHOO.COM</td>
    <td>5434534</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>24 Mar 17</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="1" class="odd" align="left" role="row">
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="chkitem" value="[{&quot;function&quot;:&quot;delete&quot;,&quot;params&quot;:&quot;1,Samuel Bepari Jones,samuelstar@gmail.com&quot;}]" name="item[]"></td>
    <td class="sorting_1"><a href="http://localhost/esurance365ec/admin/customers/show/1">Samuel Bepari Jones</a></td>
    <td>samuelstar@gmail.com</td>
    <td>0743294283</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>24 Mar 17</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="12" class="odd" align="left" role="row">
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="chkitem" value="[{&quot;function&quot;:&quot;delete&quot;,&quot;params&quot;:&quot;1,Samuel Bepari Jones,samuelstar@gmail.com&quot;}]" name="item[]"></td>
    <td class="sorting_1"><a href="http://localhost/esurance365ec/admin/customers/show/1">Samuel Bepari Jones</a></td>
    <td>samuelstar@gmail.com</td>
    <td>0743294283</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>24 Mar 17</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="9" class="odd" align="left" role="row">
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="chkitem" value="[{&quot;function&quot;:&quot;delete&quot;,&quot;params&quot;:&quot;1,Samuel Bepari Jones,samuelstar@gmail.com&quot;}]" name="item[]"></td>
    <td class="sorting_1"><a href="http://localhost/esurance365ec/admin/customers/show/1">Samuel Bepari Jones</a></td>
    <td>samuelstar@gmail.com</td>
    <td>0743294283</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>24 Mar 17</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="6" class="odd" align="left" role="row">
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="chkitem" value="[{&quot;function&quot;:&quot;delete&quot;,&quot;params&quot;:&quot;1,Samuel Bepari Jones,samuelstar@gmail.com&quot;}]" name="item[]"></td>
    <td class="sorting_1"><a href="http://localhost/esurance365ec/admin/customers/show/1">Samuel Bepari Jones</a></td>
    <td>samuelstar@gmail.com</td>
    <td>0743294283</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>24 Mar 17</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="7" class="odd" align="left" role="row">
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="chkitem" value="[{&quot;function&quot;:&quot;delete&quot;,&quot;params&quot;:&quot;1,Samuel Bepari Jones,samuelstar@gmail.com&quot;}]" name="item[]"></td>
    <td class="sorting_1"><a href="http://localhost/esurance365ec/admin/customers/show/1">Samuel Bepari Jones</a></td>
    <td>samuelstar@gmail.com</td>
    <td>0743294283</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>24 Mar 17</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="10" class="odd" align="left" role="row">
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="chkitem" value="[{&quot;function&quot;:&quot;delete&quot;,&quot;params&quot;:&quot;1,Samuel Bepari Jones,samuelstar@gmail.com&quot;}]" name="item[]"></td>
    <td class="sorting_1"><a href="http://localhost/esurance365ec/admin/customers/show/1">Samuel Bepari Jones</a></td>
    <td>samuelstar@gmail.com</td>
    <td>0743294283</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>24 Mar 17</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="11" class="odd" align="left" role="row">
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="chkitem" value="[{&quot;function&quot;:&quot;delete&quot;,&quot;params&quot;:&quot;1,Samuel Bepari Jones,samuelstar@gmail.com&quot;}]" name="item[]"></td>
    <td class="sorting_1"><a href="http://localhost/esurance365ec/admin/customers/show/1">Samuel Bepari Jones</a></td>
    <td>samuelstar@gmail.com</td>
    <td>0743294283</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>24 Mar 17</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Note:-

1.he rows count in your data is less than 10, that is also one reason that pagination will not show (but it doesn't mean that it will not work). I have added more data in code to show you that pagination is working

2.@StanleyNgumo you need to first add jQuery library and then data-table library and then your script code. Now if you are adding your script code in header then wrap your code inside `$(document).ready(function(){...});`. If you are adding the script code at footer then no need of `$(document).ready(){...});`

Comment: Before initialising the dataTable? or it can be done at the end of the page

Comment: @StanleyNgumo  you need to first add jQuery library and then data-table library and then your script code. Now if you are adding your script code in header then wrap your code inside `$(document).ready(function(){...});`. If you are adding the script code at footer then no need of `$(document).ready(){...})`

Comment: @StanleyNgumo  glad to help you:):)

Answer (score 0):

Try this data table

add on the top of your page

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
```

DataTable

```
var dataTable;
$(document).ready(function() {
   dataTable = $('#manufacturer_data').DataTable({ 
               //here's example URL from Codeigniter   
       "ajax": "<?=base_url()?>manufacturer/manufacturer_list",      
   });  
});
```

add on the bottom of your page

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's worth mentioning here that the pagination will only work with a properly formatted table.

> For DataTables to be able to enhance an HTML table, the table must be
> valid, well formatted HTML, with a header (thead) and a single body
> (tbody). An optional footer (tfoot) can also be used.

The table must be structured like this:

```
<table id="table_id" class="display">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Column 1</th>
            <th>Column 2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 1 Data 1</td>
            <td>Row 1 Data 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2 Data 1</td>
            <td>Row 2 Data 2</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```